# Since Angular 12.2.x supports rxjs 7.0.0, is 7.5.x is also compatible

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6, rxjs7

Since Angular 12.2.x branch recently added support for rxjs 7.0.0, does it mean that strictly 7.0.x is supported or we can even use 7.5.x too?

Comment: You can use both

Comment: on one of the github pages, it was mentioned that only later minor versions of 7.0.x are supported. So, i guess we can't use 7.5.x

Answer (score 1):

Here's a matrix of Angular versions as well as supported TS / RxJS.

https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

This is not an official doc but I definitely trust @LayZeeDK to proactively keep it up to date as much as possible.